# Access: Integrating Subquery into excisting Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

The "Last" function in the query below (line 4 & 5)that I'm using  is not exactly what I'm after. The last function finds the last record in that table.

**What i need find is the most recent record in the table according to a date field.**

```
SELECT
        tblinmate.statusid,
        tblinmate.activedate,
        Last(tblclassificationhistory.classificationid) AS LastOfclassificationID,
        Last(tblsquadhistory.squadid) AS LastOfsquadID,
        tblperson.firstname,
        tblperson.middlename,
        tblperson.lastname,
        tblinmate.prisonnumber,
        tblinmate.droppeddate,
        tblinmate.personid,
        tblinmate.inmateid
FROM tblsquad
INNER JOIN (tblperson
INNER JOIN ((tblinmate
INNER JOIN (tblclassification
INNER JOIN tblclassificationhistory
        ON tblclassification.classificationid =
        tblclassificationhistory.classificationid)
        ON tblinmate.inmateid =
        tblclassificationhistory.inmateid)
INNER JOIN tblsquadhistory
        ON tblinmate.inmateid =
        tblsquadhistory.inmateid)
        ON tblperson.personid = tblinmate.personid)
        ON tblsquad.squadid = tblsquadhistory.squadid
GROUP BY tblinmate.statusid,
         tblinmate.activedate,
         tblperson.firstname,
         tblperson.middlename,
         tblperson.lastname,
         tblinmate.prisonnumber,
         tblinmate.droppeddate,
         tblinmate.personid,
         tblinmate.inmateid;
```

This query below does just that, finds the most recent record in a table according to a date field.

**my problem is i dont know how to integrate this Query into the above to replace the "Last" function**

```
SELECT a.inmateID,
       a.classificationID,
       b.max_date
FROM (
    SELECT tblClassificationHistory.inmateID, 
           tblClassificationHistory.classificationID,                
           tblClassificationHistory.reclassificationDate
    FROM tblinmate
    INNER JOIN tblClassificationHistory
    ON tblinmate.inmateID = tblClassificationHistory.inmateID 
) a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT tblClassificationHistory.inmateID, 
           MAX(tblClassificationHistory.reclassificationDate) as max_date
    FROM tblinmate
    INNER JOIN tblClassificationHistory
    ON tblinmate.inmateID = tblClassificationHistory.inmateID
    GROUP BY tblClassificationHistory.inmateID  
) b
ON a.inmateID = b.inmateID
AND a.reclassificationDate = b.max_date
ORDER BY a.inmateID;
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got a tip from another forum to combine queries like this

```
SELECT qryMainTemp.*, qrySquad.*, qryClassification.*
FROM (qryMainTemp INNER JOIN qrySquad ON qryMainTemp.inmateID = qrySquad.inmateID) INNER JOIN qryClassification ON qryMainTemp.inmateID = qryClassification.inmateID;
```

and it worked :) i separated the first query into the two queries it was made of and then combined the three like shown above.

Sadly this made another problem arise the query is now not up-datable..working on a solution for this